# How to set decimals to only 2 digits in Doubles?

Tags: java, android

In my response i am getting the value as `80.00000`

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
TextField.setText(df.format(Double.parseDouble(custom.getValue())));
```

My problem is i am getting 80.000, i am doing a parseDouble which will return a primitive double type and i am doing a format to this double to `2 decimals`.

Why am i getting `80` instead of `80.00`?

I changed my way and tried with this.

```
TextField.setText(String.format("%2f",Double.parseDouble(custom.getValue())));
```

Now i am geting `80.000000` instead of `80.00`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should be `"%.2f"` instead of `"%2f"`

```
TextField.setText(String.format("%.2f",Double.parseDouble(custom.getValue())));
```

you forget to add the `.`

Answer (score 2):

> Why am i getting 80 instead of 80.00?

The first example should be:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
```

Otherwise any non significant fractional digits will be suppressed.

Answer (score 2):

`java.text.NumberFormat` is a good alternative

```
final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
System.out.println(nf.format(123456789.123456789));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `%2f` to `%.2f` in the String.format parameter.