# Kotlin Float.toString and/or String.format

Tags: kotlin

I have a `Float` that I'd like to format as a percentage. If it was C# then it would be `f.ToString("P1")`. However, as far as I can tell, this is not possible in Kotlin.

The documentation is woefully inadeuate:

- https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-float/to-string.html
- https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/format.html

So do you all have to write your own number formatting code?

Comment: You're running code on the JVM. The whole JDK, and all its documentation, is available to you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954443/how-do-i-format-my-percent-variable-to-2-decimal-places for examples.

Comment: No, it's not Java, it's Kotlin.

Does Kotlin have documentation for string formatting?

Comment: Kotlin is interoperable with Java. If you run your code on the JVM (as your links to the jvm documentation pages of Kotlin seem to indicate), you can use any class of the JDK. Do you understand that?